# How to git init a remote branch instead of master

Tags: git, github

I was asked to copy my team's remote branch, called v8.1, to my local. I am to do a bug fix against this branch.

In Github, I went to Code, switched to v8.1 and copied the SSH command, running it in Terminal:
git clone git@github.company.com:folderName/repoName.git

Later, I realized I had not copied Remote Branch v8.1. I had copied Master.
In Terminal, "git branch" reveals only 1 branch: master
Is there a way to do a "git checkout -b" from Remote v8.1?

I guess my mental model of Remote Branching is off. Please clarify.

Comment: This question is not specific to Salesforce and belongs somewhere else, such as [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Once you have a clone, simply check out the required branch.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general sense, you should first fetch to make sure you have the latest branches, then do a normal checkout:

```
git fetch
git checkout v8.1
```

Do not use `-b`, as you are not intending to create a new local branch. The branch will automatically be downloaded from the remote and checked out.

Comment: Thanks! I knew this, but it's been a couple years. Amazing how my hard drive gets wiped clean in a couple years.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely It's not just you. I can't tell you how many times I've googled something only to find the number one search result was something I wrote years ago.